# Opengl increase in speed after few seconds

Tags: opengl

I am developing a rendering engine with OpenGL as base renderer.
The renderer start with 150 fps in beginning and after 30 seconds or so the fps increases to 500.
I have timed each part of the engine separately and the only part that increase in speed is the drawMesh function which binds the [static]VBOs and calls the glDrawArrays.

I have also commented the glPush and glGet functions with the same behavior as result.

This happens every time i run the engine, even when the camera is not moved and remains rendering the exact same scene.

Does anyone has any idea how this can be happening?

Comment: I would aregue that is a result of a caching mechanism of the hardware.  GPUs work somewhat similarly to a CPU in that they have super fast cache, L2, sometimes L3, then external RAM.  What you may be seeing is a result of the GPU finally getting everything into the GPU ordered the way it is most efficient for drawing after a couple frames.  All data when transfering to the GPU will begin by transfering to the external RAM as no DMA engine has the ability to PUSH data directly to the GPU cache.  After GPU brings it in, and learns what to swap and not, performance can get better.

Comment: Unfortunately, speaking from only a software point of view, when we make a call to opengl, it is difficult to say what the hardware does with it after that.  Thus this is somewhat an open ended question and answer.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing, but the same happens when i set my VBOs as dynamic and also there is very little on screen, 6 textures and about 100k vertices.
but it's still a possibility, and very hard to say what is happening on hardware indeed.

Comment: I would think that cache could only explain the first frame being slow. After the first frame, the cache is "warm" and performance of all later frames should be the same for a static scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

The problem arises from the VBO being mapped to a buffer after being created. The model class does this once to update its boundaries; and in case of particles to update the buffer with required data.

As it seems the video-card (or at least in my case having a *Geforce GTS 450*) does not copy the data back into the video-card directly after unmapping the VBO, specially when using the GL_READ_WRITE_ARB flag for mapping the buffer. it will keep the data in external RAM for few seconds before copying the data back into the VRAM.

**The solution**

By using the GL_READ_ONLY_ARB flag to map the data which are supposed to only read the data, the buffer will get copied back into the VRAM almost directly. However in my case it would be much more efficient to calculate the boundaries during the mesh conversation and not accessing the data at all once the VBO is created for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because shaders are compiled just-in-time before first usage.

Take a look at [GL_ARB_get_program_binary](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/get_program_binary.txt)

Also, try rendering a triangle ( can probably do this off screen) with your shaders as you load them during the initialization phase.

Comment: I am using ubershaders. so yes the shaders are build on runtime, but the speed increase is about 30 seconds after everything is compiled and rendering.
no new shaders are build after the first run, since it is a pretty simple scene for testing.

Comment: Not sure I agree with this answer, as if the performance is increased after display has already occured, then the just-in-time compilation has already occured, otherwise there really wouldnt be any displaying already going on!